# How can I use newlib with android NDK?

Tags: android-ndk, newlib

Can I use newlib or newlib-nano with android NDK to build a dynamic library?
I know this is not a to-the-point question. But couldn't find much write-up on this. Any help is appreciated. I'm a newbie to android.

Comment: Why would you need to? Android already has a C runtime.

Comment: @DanAlbert I have a dynamic library. I have to reduce its size. I tried most of the optimization flags like -fvisibility=hidden -flto -Os -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections etc. I am trying to reduce it further more.

Comment: Why do you expect using newlib to decrease the size of your library?

Comment: @DanAlbert I assume the functions in newlib are smaller than the standard libc.
So if the compiler is inlining (intrinsic)functions from libc, if newlib is used, it might reduce the size, won't it?

Comment: libc is part of the system that isn't included in your app. There are a small number of functions in the headers that are inlinable, but it's not the norm. You're talking about including the entirety of newlib in your app to avoid a few trivial inline functions that may not be any larger in bionic than in newlib. newlib isn't magically smaller. Beyond all that, you can't replace libc in an Android app. libc is already loaded by the zygote, and trying to replace is is going to break everything. It sounds a lot like you're optimizing prematurely without data. libc is almost none of your app.

Comment: Thank you @DanAlbert. You are correct. I found all the inline functions in my code, and only a few were from libc. So there was no point in changing the libc and break the rest. I was able to do lot more optimization using the CFlags itself.
NB:- Sorry for the late reply, I was caught up with other activities. Saw your reply just now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android uses bionic, not newlib. The C runtime is already loaded as part of the zygote in any app so this is not optional.